# i am not able to get link from xml feed reader...it showing me only Tag"?<link>" but not displaying The url in link

Tags: android

I am not able to get link from xml feed reader. It shows me only `Tag"?<link>"` but not displaying The url in link.

I am using this in rss feed reader.

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
                    Elements itemElements = doc.getElementsByTag("item");
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
                        Element item = itemElements.get(i);
                        String title = removeCdata(item.child(0).text());
                        String pubDate = item.child(2).text();

                        String link = item.child(1).text();
                        //String link = u.substring(u.indexOf("<link>") + 1, u.indexOf("</link>"));


                        NewsItem news = new NewsItem();
                        news.title = title;

                        news.link = link;

                        news.date = pubDate;
                        newsItemList.add(news);

                        Log.i("mytag", "title: " + title);
                        Log.i("mytag", "pubdate: " + pubDate);
                        Log.i("mytag", "guid:  " + link);

                    }
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i("mytag", "items found: " + itemElements.size());
                    Log.i("mytag", "items in news List: " + newsItemList.size());
                    adapter = new NewsAdapter(BoardOfInvestment.this, newsItemList);
                    lvNews.setAdapter(adapter);
                    lvNews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            NewsItem currentNews = newsItemList.get(i);
                            String url = currentNews.link;
                            System.out.println(url);
                            System.out.println(currentNews.date);
                            System.out.println(currentNews.link);
                            // Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                            //browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            //getApplicationContext().
                            // startActivity(browserIntent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
```